# I am trying to call a python script recommend.py from my PHP file. Is it the correct way ? No results are obtained

Tags: php, python

The four parameters values are taken from the database. The python script has the algorithm to make recomeendation based on the four paramters specified.

```
<?php
include('main.php'); 
$lat = $_POST['lt'];
$lon = $_POST['ln'];
$uid = $_POST['id'];
$rad = $_POST['rd'];
#$lat = "28.674558";
#$lon = "77.274202";``
#$uid = "1";
#$rad = "1";
$outs = 'python recommend.py' . $uid . ' ' . $lat . ' ' . $lon . ' ' . $rad;

$output = shell_exec($outs);

echo $output;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a space after  recommend.py while concatinating `$outs`

```
<?php
    include('main.php'); 
    $lat = $_POST['lt'];
    $lon = $_POST['ln'];
    $uid = $_POST['id'];
    $rad = $_POST['rd'];
    #$lat = "28.674558";
    #$lon = "77.274202";``
    #$uid = "1";
    #$rad = "1";
    $outs = 'python recommend.py ' . $uid . ' ' . $lat . ' ' . $lon . ' ' . $rad;

    $output = shell_exec($outs);

    echo $output;

    ?>
```

Comment: Its still the same. Also, any idea on the fact that this code is working fine on a friend's lappy having Ubuntu ?

Comment: Do you get any error?  Can you echo $outs and see what gets printed?  You may want to copy the exact value of $outs printed and try to run it in command line and observe the behavior. Also, check if you have any permission issues.